# Web api, calling any function in the api thourgh Postman- not working

Tags: c#, .net, postman, asp.net-web-api2

Very weird problen (weird- cause it worked before).
I am calling the web api Get function on X controller, like this(from PostMan):

[image: Postman]

But the break point, never hits:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(){}
```

This is "Global.asax"

```
 protected void Application_Start()
  {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   

 }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        }
```

I already tried solutions in Stackoverflow, but none worked for me.

Can someone direct me to the answer?

- the address, without the api/controler, its is working.

Comment: Please, paste code as a text using code formatting, rather than images

Comment: But I guess an issue in your routing template, cause you have `{action}` in there, so seems you have to call your api with `/api/Employee/Get`. If you want to call your api in *REST*-style (`/api/Employee`), I guess you have to change your route template to `api/{controller}/{id}`

Comment: i changed the images to code. now it's working* but *only in debug mode*, and when i am trying to call a custom method (get) with [httpget] and [route("api/Employee/GetAllDepartmentNames")] as attribute, its calling to Get method and not the custom one

Comment: don't post your solution as update to a question. post answer instead

Answer (score 0):

now its working , what i did is,
in `WebApiConfig.cs`, I changed the register method like this:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "ActionApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

this was the old register method:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

and the custom method attribute(without **):

```
**[ActionName("AllDepartmentNames")]**
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage AllDepartmentNames()
{...}
```